# SQL Cause of table updates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to determine *how* a table is updated? I have a table that is being updated and I can't figure out how; by an agent job? ssis package? trigger?

I've queried against dm_exec_query_stats and dm_exec_sql_text to determine the statement that is being run, but I don't know where it's being executed from.

```
SELECT SQL_HANDLE, deqs.plan_handle, deqs.last_execution_time,
       dest.text
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
WHERE dest.text LIKE '%Update%'
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time desc
```

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: Thanks HABO, I've corrected the tags with the necessary info.

Comment: You should search your code for the update statement. There isn't a way to know that code being executed is from an ssis package or a trigger. It is all just code. You might be able to gain some insight from the connection information but it will still require some digging. You might want to look at SQL Search from redgate. It is free and is an excellent searching tool.

Comment: When searching for the `update` statement, keep in mind that it might be in pieces/parts, e.g. dynamic SQL, assembled within an application from various resources, ... . A traditional, if impractical, approach is to secure the table against updates and see who complains. If you can explicitly grant permissions to all of the known sources and then disable other access you'll turn up the culprit.

Comment: @HABO I decided to try something similar... The table appears to update exactly every 15 minutes... which would lead me to believe it's something on a schedule; like an Agent job. I decided to lock the table a few minutes before the table updates. I should get an email if something breaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this may not be a good way to do this and I might get burned for this but, here's what I did...

I executed an open transaction against the table; locking it.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT 
    TOP 1 * 
FROM *tbl*
```

I then queried dm_exec_requests to find the session_id that is being run

```
SELECT 
    sqltext.TEXT,
    req.session_id
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
```

I then queried dm_exec_sessions to find the host_name and program_name that is running that session.

```
SELECT 
    host_name, 
    login_time, 
    program_name 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions 
WHERE session_id = 184
```

I was able to determine that the culprit was an SSIS package hosted on a different server. Close the locking transaction

Thanks everyone for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Use this query for any dependent stored procedure that has insert/update/select queries for a particular table . Alternatively if you have a trigger on the table which captures inserted datetime , you can analyse by checking current running queries.

It would need a lot of digging of any SSIS jobs are scheduled for table update, usually most updates are done through SP's. This below query is only a quick check.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referencing.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(referencing.object_id)) AS SprocName
    ,QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referenced.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(referenced.object_id)) AS ReferencedObjectName
    ,referenced.type_desc AS ReferencedObjectType
FROM sys.sql_dependencies d
INNER JOIN sys.procedures referencing ON referencing.object_id = d.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects referenced ON referenced.object_id = d.referenced_major_id
WHERE referencing.type_desc = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'
    AND referenced.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
ORDER BY SprocName
    ,ReferencedObjectName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out if your table is referenced in any `stored procedure`, `function`, `view` or `triggger` with this code

suppose the table you are looking for is called `tblMyTable`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       o.name AS Object_Name,
       o.type_desc,
       m.*
FROM   sys.sql_modules m
  INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE m.definition Like '%tblMyTable%';
```

This will return any `stored procedure`, `function`, `view` or `triggger` that has `tblMyTable` in its text, so even if it only just reads from it.
So you need to check each one to see if its updating or not.
Yes its some work, but at least it gives you a change to find out if the update is coming from any object in your database.

If this returns nothing then you know that you have to search in your client software.